# How can I filter intems by `count(*)` without `having`?

Tags: sql

I have some query:

```
select disconnect_reason as disconnectReason, disconnect_cause, count(*) as callsCount 
from calls group by disconnect_reason, disconnect_cause
```

How I need to get items with callsCount = 1 only.
How can I get it without `having`?

Comment: What's wrong with using `having`?

Comment: try sub query in where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always you can use `Having` clause to filter the groups but if you want a another way then try something like this

```
select * from 
(
select disconnect_reason as disconnectReason, disconnect_cause, count(*) as callsCount 
from calls group by disconnect_reason, disconnect_cause
) A
Where callsCount = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try using **CTE** For **MS SQL SERVER**

```
with cte
as
(
select disconnect_reason as disconnectReason, disconnect_cause, count(*) as callsCount 
from calls group by disconnect_reason, disconnect_cause 
)
select * from cte where callsCount >0
```

Comment: Not all database engines support this.  The OP did not specify his.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
(
select disconnect_reason as disconnectReason, disconnect_cause, count(*) as callsCount 
from calls group by disconnect_reason, disconnect_cause
)base
where  callsCount = 1
```